# Duda Mysql Sumar Registro Anterior

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Actualmente estoy trabajando con una base de datos Mysql No relacional. Necesito de una forma, crear un procedimiento almacenado, que este pueda sumar el registro anterior y restar por otro campo.

Cree un Excel con la fórmula, para ejemplificar el caso.

**Edit**

Actualmente poseo dos tablas llamada Resoluciones y Retenciones las cuales Retenciones sé cual es mi primer registro y luego, viene las resoluciones. Adjunto Excel completo de la formula.

Los registros poseen primary key.

[image: Formula]

Todo lo que he buscado en google no se acerca a lo que necesito programar.

Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! por mas que no crees claves, y la manejes como "no relacional" mysql es una base de datos relacional. Dicho eso, como sabes cual es el registro anterior? las bases de datos no tienen orden en sus registros. deberias mostrar como estan los datos y como esperas saber cual es el registro anterior

Comment: Hola gbianchi. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La verdad es mi primera vez acá y la pregunta puede que no haya quedado bien formulada al principio.

Comment: Es imposible ayudarte con la información que proporcionas, para empezar tus tablas deben de tener una llave primaria que sea unica e irrepetible para identidicar a un registro, a lo mejor a lo que te refieres es que no tienes la llaves foraneas registradas como tal, agrega la infromación de tu base, las consultas que has intentado y solo así podremos orientarte.

Comment: editala con el boton [edit]. Agrega toda la informacion que haga falta hasta que no queden dudas sobre que preguntas.

Comment: @M.Gress es perfectamente posible hacer una tabla sin llaves de ningun tipo.. pero bue.. todo va a costar un monton.

Comment: Ricardo lees los enlaces que te pase tambien!

Comment: Perfecto. 

Estoy leyendo los enlaces. Ahora proporcioné más información a la pregunta.